# Python dictionary comprehension with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dict-comprehension

I am trying to create a dictionary from two columns of a DataFrame (df)

```
mydict={x :y for x in df['Names'] for y in df['Births']}
```

But all of the values are the same(the last value in the column)!

```
{'Bob': 973, 'Jessica': 973, 'John': 973, 'Mary': 973, 'Mel': 973}
```

I checked the column and it has many other values, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Check `df[['Names', 'Births']].set_index('Names').to_dict()['Births']`.

Comment: Because dictionary keys can only store one value, and you are setting each key with each value, so it store the last one it was set with.

Comment: Try `dict(zip(dff['Names'], dff['Births']))`.

Comment: Thanks for the help but I know this solution I was looking for a way to do it using the comprehension

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think Abdou hit the nail on the head with `dict(zip(dff['Names'], dff['Births']))`, but if you want to do it with a dict comprehension you can do this:

```
    In [1]: import pandas as pd

    In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame(
       ...: [{'Births': 971, 'Names': 'Bob'},
       ...:  {'Births': 972, 'Names': 'Jessica'},
       ...:  {'Births': 973, 'Names': 'John'},
       ...:  {'Births': 974, 'Names': 'Mary'},
       ...:  {'Births': 975, 'Names': 'Mel'}])

    In [3]: {d['Names']: d['Births'] for d in df.to_dict(orient='records')}
    Out[3]: {'Bob': 971, 'Jessica': 972, 'John': 973, 'Mary': 974, 'Mel': 975}
```

Answer (score 0):

try
my_dict = {row.Names:row.Births for (index,row) in df.iterows()}

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).